# How to align image in table td, tcpdf

Tags: php, html, image, alignment, tcpdf

I use tcpdf to generate pdf files.

And there's a problem in aligning image in table td.

I am uising `$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');` in tcpdf.

[image]

html is clear from the image i have shared.
html is just simple as

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>Picture</td>
    .......
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="abc.jpg" width="20" height="20" ></td>
    .......
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: align="center", valign="middle" , css margin and padding ... nothing seems to work I tried on

text-align:center push into center but not vertically.

Comment: did you check appling <td align="center">

Comment: @gayan . this doesn't work

Comment: have you tried `text-align: center;` on the `td`?

Comment: just check in this way give some space 
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="abc.jpg" width="20" height="20" ></td>

Comment: @FDL yes this align it horizontally . but still need to align it vertically

Comment: How about adding `vertical-align: middle;` aswell as `text-align:center;` then? Does that work?

Comment: Will add as answer, so others can benefit in future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following CSS to your `td` should work:

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

See [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwkMk/) of it working.

Comment: Unfortunatly, work on HTML, but don't work when you throw the HTML to TCPDF. :(

Comment: text-align:center is OK. vertical-align: middle; : Not OK. Must try with setHtmlVSpace and a p/div/h5 or h6 inside the cell ....

Answer (score 2):

Did you check image alignment?

```
<img align=center src="abc.jpg" width="20" height="20" >
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. As shown below, we can add a line break inside the `<p>` tag.

```
<table width="100%" style="border:1px solid #000;">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <p><br/>
                <img src="path/to/image" />
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use :
CSS:

```
td img{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

or use  like @gayan

Comment: tcpdf, not css. tcpdf don't have margin in writeHtml